# Dynamically Add/Remove Attribute Directive based on state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to build a directive that adds and remove a second directive based on a boolean flag.

So, when boolFlag = true, the div in example.html should recompile to include my-dir as an attribute. And it should have additional attributes required by my-dir in the form of "test=1".

Here is the basics of what I have so far:

example.html ----

```
<div add-remove when={{boolFlag}} dir-name="my-dir" dir-attrs="test, 1"></div>
```

add-remove-directive.js ----

```
function($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var attrArray = attrs.dirAttrs.split(',');
    for (a in attrArray) {
      attrArray[a] = attrArray[a].trim();
    }
    attrs.$observe('when', function() {
    // flagged when the directive should be attached to the element
      var isWhen = attrs.when === 'true';
      if (isWhen) {
       for (a = 0; a < attrArray.length; a+=2) {
         elem.attr(attrArray[a], attrArray[a+1]);
       }
       newScope = scope.$new();
       cElem = $compile(elem)(newScope);
       elem.replaceWith(cElem);
       $timeout(function() {
         scope.$destroy();
       });
    }
    // if the flag is not set, remove the dynamic directive from the element
    // but only if the element already has the given directive
    else {
        normDirName = attrs.$normalize(attrs.dirName);
        console.log(normDirName);
        console.log(r, 'elsed', attrs);
        if (!attrs.hasOwnProperty(normDirName)) return;

        elem.removeAttr(scope.dirName);
        for (a = 0; a < attrArray.length; a+=2) {
          elem.removeAttr(attrArray[a]);
        }
        newScope = scope.$new();
        cElem = $compile(elem)(newScope);
        elem.replaceWith(cElem);
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.$destroy();
        });
      }
  }

}
```

**---EDIT---**

Sorry, that was an error with me copying it over from my project. It is functional up to how I described in the original post.

Basically where it's at now is I can dynamically "my-dir" directive correctly with the corresponding required attributes "test=1".

But the problems I'm running into are:

- that there are two scopes active the original one without "my-dir" and another scope WITH "my-dir".
- my else statement doesn't properly remove "my-dir" from the div when boolFlag is set to false.

Comment: The `return` part isn't valid javascript. You sure that's how your code is set up and partially working? A demo would help also to see what's going on better

Comment: I've added the rest of the Angular directive headers that I had missed while copying over the code from my project